# Which scala version uses Play! framework 2.1?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a Java Play! project. When I import it to IntelliJ I can see in my target folder a scala-2.10/ folder. But when I look in my project/target/ folder, I have a scala-2-9-2 folder. How comes this and how to know which scala version is really used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in `project/target` is the Scala version used by the build system.  Those artifacts are not the result of your project's code but rather the build system.

The artifacts in `target` **are** from your code.

In any case, you can determine the Scala version in use with the `show scalaVersion` command:

```
$ sbt 'show scalaVersion'
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/ryantanner/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ryantanner/myproj/project
[info] Set current project to MyProj (in build file:/Users/ryantanner/myproj/)
[info] 2.10.5
```